# Selenium not displaying table content after button click

Tags: python, selenium, csv, button, python-requests

I am trying to download multiple csv files from the below url and hoping to use selenium or any other method for it. The url requires filling up of a form that includes selecting options from multiple dropdowns. Then, an 'image' button needs to be clicked for the download link to appear.
If I run selenium chrome driver from python and click on the button, nothing appears. I am also unable to figure out the url of the csv files so they could be downloaded using 'requests' or 'urllib'.

Here's the url I need to download from:
https://www1.nseindia.com/products/content/derivatives/equities/historical_fo.htm

Here's my code so far:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())

url = 'https://www1.nseindia.com/products/content/derivatives/equities/historical_fo.htm'
driver.get(url)
instr_type = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('instrumentType'))
symbol = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('symbol'))
opt_type = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('optionType'))
date_range = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('dateRange'))
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@src='/common/images/btn-get-data.gif' and @type='image']")

instr_type.select_by_visible_text('Index Options')
symbol.select_by_visible_text('NIFTY 50')
opt_type.select_by_visible_text('CE')
date_range.select_by_visible_text('90 Days')
button.click()
```

And this is what happens in the selenium driver -

[image: Selenium button click result]

Any thoughts on how to download the csv files from above link? Doesn't necessarily have to be using selenium.

Comment: don't you get any error message when you click it? Did you wait/sleep for download link ?

Comment: this page doesn't work for me when I use Selenium with Chrome or Firefox but it works in Chrome and Firefox without Selenium - it may have some conflict with Selenium or it uses some system to block scripts which use Selenium

Comment: I can get table as HTML using `requests` but I have to set correct `user-agent` - at least short `'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'`. Without `user-agent` code is hanging and never ends. Maybe browser with Selenium has similar problem. But I don't know if it can be fixed.

Comment: I see it uses JavaScript to get data from this HTML and generate CSV converted to base64 and embed directly in link. So maybe it would be faster and simpler to get HTML with data and scrape data with `BeautifulSoup` or `lxml`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to resolve problem with `Selenium` but I now how to get it with `requests` and `BeautifulSoup`

This page sends your options from form to this page as values directly in this URL (not as `POST`)

https://www1.nseindia.com/products/dynaContent/common/productsSymbolMapping.jsp

and server sends back `HTML` with table and also all data in `<div id="csvContentDiv">`.
This tag has all data as text already formatted to save in `csv` - it need only to replace `:` with `\n`

---

**EDIT:**

Sometimes server gives me `Status 405 Method Not Allowed` so I added  `requests.Session()` to get cookies and maybe it will work better.

---

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

session = requests.Session()
session.headers.update({'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})

# --- main page ---
url = 'https://www1.nseindia.com/products/content/derivatives/equities/historical_fo.htm'
r = session.get(url)
#print(r.status_code)

# --- table ---

url = 'https://www1.nseindia.com/products/dynaContent/common/productsSymbolMapping.jsp'

payload = {
    'instrumentType': 'OPTIDX',
    'symbol': 'NIFTY',
    'expiryDate': 'select',
    'optionType': 'CE',
    'strikePrice': '',
    'dateRange': '3month', 
    'fromDate': '',
    'toDate': '',
    'segmentLink': '9',
    'symbolCount':'',
}

r = session.get(url, params=payload)
#print(r.text)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
data = soup.find('div', {'id': 'csvContentDiv'})
#print(data.text)
data = data.text.replace(':', '\n')

with open('output.csv', 'w') as fh:
    fh.write(data)

print(data)
```

Server doesn't send data if you don't use real `User-Agent` - at least short `'Mozilla/5.0'`

---

I found this url using `DevTools` in Firefox/Chrome, tab `Network`. And later I get response from this url and manually check what I get and I found `csv` data. But I expected that I would have to scrape data from HTML table in this response.

Comment: Thanks. 
I seem to be getting a 'HTTP Status 405 Method Not Allowed' error with the above code. What am I missing?

Comment: as I said - probably it checks cookies so now in answer I added `Session()` and I read your original url before I read url with data. This way it sends request with cookies. When I was testing old version then I had original page opened in browser and maybe server was thinking that all is OK. But now it works for me even when I close browser.

Comment: this code seems OK but if you still get error 405 then maybe server checks something more (ie, header for XHR reuqests) or server is more restricted for users from some regions - I connect from Poland.

Comment: I just noticed the updated answer. Thanks for the edit... Unfortunately, I am still getting the same error. Maybe it is restricted for my region or I may not be using the right headers. In case there is anything else I could try, do let me know.